# UPnP Library for Qt WinCE

Tags: qt, windows-ce, upnp, dlna

I am trying to write DLNA project in Qt WinCE. Is there any UPnP library for it?
I am now trying CyberLink C library. But, it only has wrapper for Objective-C. 
I got some configuration errors while trying to translate Objective-C wrapper to Qt WinCE wrapper.

Errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GetAdaptersInfo referenced in function cg_net_gethostinterfaces   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol freeaddrinfo referenced in function cg_net_selectaddr cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol freeaddrinfo  cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol getaddrinfo referenced in function cg_net_selectaddr  cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol getaddrinfo   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ntohl referenced in function cg_net_selectaddr    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSAStartup referenced in function cg_socket_startup   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSACleanup referenced in function cg_socket_cleanup   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol setsockopt referenced in function cg_socket_setid cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol closesocket referenced in function cg_socket_close    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol recv referenced in function cg_socket_close   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   12  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol shutdown referenced in function cg_socket_close   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   13  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol listen referenced in function cg_socket_listen    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol getnameinfo referenced in function cg_socket_accept   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   15  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol getsockname referenced in function cg_socket_accept   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol accept referenced in function cg_socket_accept    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   17  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol send referenced in function cg_socket_write   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol recvfrom referenced in function cg_socket_recv    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gethostbyname referenced in function cg_socket_tosockaddrin   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   20  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol inet_addr referenced in function cg_socket_tosockaddrin   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   21  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol htons referenced in function cg_socket_tosockaddrin   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   22  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol htonl referenced in function cg_socket_tosockaddrin   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   23  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol WSAGetLastError referenced in function cg_socket_getlasterror cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   24  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol bind referenced in function cg_socket_bind    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   25  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol socket referenced in function cg_socket_bind  cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   26  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol connect referenced in function cg_socket_connect  cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   27  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sendto referenced in function cg_socket_sendto    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   28  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XML_ParserFree referenced in function cg_xml_parse    cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   29  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XML_Parse referenced in function cg_xml_parse cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   30  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XML_SetCharacterDataHandler referenced in function cg_xml_parse   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   31  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XML_SetElementHandler referenced in function cg_xml_parse cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   32  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XML_SetUserData referenced in function cg_xml_parse   cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
Error   33  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol XML_ParserCreate referenced in function cg_xml_parse  cyberlinkc.lib  QtUpnp
```

Please share some hints or sample codes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any UPnP library for it?

You can try GUpnp

http://gupnp.org/downloads/gupnp-dlna-0.3.0

or try Developer Tools for UPnP to generate skeleton code

http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp